# Loop to identify and fill blanks in with R-1C formula

Tags: vba, loops

I am trying to run a loop over two rows and 19 columns to pull down the first value of blank cells. Any suggestions? I keep getting a compile error:

> invalid Next contrl variable reference.

```
Sub Loop1()

    Dim R As Integer
    Dim C As Integer

    R = 18
    C = 1

    For R = 18 To 20
    For C = 1 To 19
        If Cells(R, C) = "" Then Cells(R, C).Value = "=R[-1]C"

    Next R
    Next C


End Sub
```

Comment: Try `... Then Cells(R, C).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"`.

Comment: @Jeeped, thanks, I just lucked into the same part myself, but changed the question a little bit.

Comment: try switching `Next C` and `Next R`, and you don't need to declare `R = 18` `C = 1`

Comment: Perfect! Works how I wanted it to.